# Added on to my cabin adding a 100 amp sub panel have a little less then 50 foot to run a feeder wire for sub panel in crawl space

Tags: subpanel

looking to find out I have a 50 foot run from main panel to sub panel all in a crawl space I have 50 foot of 2.2.2.4 dyke Quaddrplex aluminum conductor underground direct burial 600v URD, can I use this wire without a conduit or not

Comment: I think if it is possible to touch it with bare skin by walking/crawling around, they want it protected from touching.

Comment: Please clarify the question and add punctuation. I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: #2 is only good to 90A.  Most of the time that's plenty.  If you need honest 100A you need #1.  *I'm guessing you were told #2 is for 100A. This is a common mistake people make, because they are confusing "services" and "feeders"*.

Answer (score 2):

### You'll probably need a different cable

URD cable cannot be exposed without a conduit, to begin with, and your URD may  not even be usable *at all* for this application as single-rated USE cable can't be used for interior or aboveground wiring, conduit or no conduit, as per NEC 338.12(B):

> **(B) Underground Service-Entrance Cable.**
>
> Underground service-entrance cable (USE) shall not be used under the
> following conditions or in the following locations:
>
> (1) For interior wiring
>
> (2) For aboveground installations except where USE cable
> emerges from the ground and is terminated in an enclosure at an outdoor location and the cable is protected in accordance with 300.5(D)
>
> (3) As aerial cable unless it is a multiconductor cable identified for use aboveground and installed as messenger-supported wiring in accordance with 225.10 and Part II of Article 396

So, unless your URD is marked as tri-rated cable (USE(-2)/RHH/RHW(-2) instead of just USE, which also implies that it uses AA-8000 series alloy aluminum), then you can't legally use it for this, even in a conduit.  Or in other words, *go get wires that will actually work for this application, by Code*, then send the URD off to the Can-Pak for recycling.

### Furthermore, you got wires that were one gauge too small

Furthermore, if you want to run a full 100A to your subpanel, you'll need 1AWG aluminum wire for that -- under the NEC ampacity rules, you can only run 90A on 2AWG Al unless it's feeding an entire dwelling unit, despite what the cablemakers say.

So, I'd get a 1-1-1-3 SER cable for this job, or individual 1AWG Al THHN or XHHW-2 wires if you are running a conduit instead of a cable.